# Is there a way to have only one wrapper for two functions with different signatures

Tags: c, wrapper, typedef

I have to define some wrapper function in order to expand the functionalities of the wrapped ones.

In general, the functions have this signature:

```
coco_problem_t f_<function_name>_bbob_problem_allocate(
   const size_t function,
   const size_t dimension,
   const size_t instance,
   const long rseed,
   const char *problem_id_template,
   const char *problem_name_template)
```

So basically there are around 20 functions with this signature, and that i could easily wrap around by creating a function template type and pass it as argument type to the wrapper function.

Something like:

1. Defining the function type to be passed as argument type to the wrapper function

   ```
   typedef coco_problem_t *(*coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t)(
     const size_t function,
     const size_t dimension,
     const size_t instance,
     const long rseed,
     const char *problem_id_template,
     const char *problem_name_template);
   ```
2. Signature of the wrapper function

   ```
   coco_noisy_problem_t *coco_problem_allocate_bbob_wrap_noisy(
       coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t coco_problem_bbob_allocator,
       const size_t function,
       const size_t dimension,
       const size_t instance,
       const long rseed,
       const char *problem_id_template,
       const char *problem_name_template );
   ```

And in this way I can easily wrap around those functions.

However, there are exactly two functions for which the signature is slightly different:

1. The first one takes an additional double parameter and its signature is something like:

   ```
    coco_problem_t f_<function_name>_bbob_problem_allocate(
        const size_t function,
        const size_t dimension,
        const size_t instance,
        const long rseed,
        const double conditioning,
        const char *problem_id_template,
        const char *problem_name_template)`
   ```
2. The other one takes an additional size_t parameter and its signature is something like:

   ```
    coco_problem_t f_<function_name>_bbob_problem_allocate(
        const size_t function,
        const size_t dimension,
        const size_t instance,
        const long rseed,
        const size_t n_peaks,
        const char *problem_id_template,
        const char *problem_name_template)`
   ```

I can see how it is possible to solve this problem by  defining two more function types

1. One for passing the function with the additional double parameter:

   ```
      typedef coco_problem_t *(*coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t_conditioned)(
         const size_t function,
         const size_t dimension,
         const size_t instance,
         const long rseed,
         const double conditioning,
         const char *problem_id_template,
         const char *problem_name_template);`
   ```
2. The other for passing the function with the additional size_t parameter:

   ```
    typedef coco_problem_t *(*coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t_n_peaks)(
        const size_t function,
        const size_t dimension,
        const size_t instance,
        const long rseed,
        const size_t n_peaks,
        const char *problem_id_template,
        const char *problem_name_template);`
   ```

And then creating one wrapper for each, something like:

1. Wrapper for the function with the extra double parameter:

   ```
    coco_noisy_problem_t *coco_problem_allocate_bbob_wrap_noisy_conditioned(
        coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t_conditioned coco_problem_bbob_allocator,
        const size_t function,
        const size_t dimension,
        const size_t instance,
        const long rseed,
        const double conditioning,
        const char *problem_id_template,
        const char *problem_name_template );`
   ```
2. Wrapper for the function with the extra size_t parameter:

   ```
    coco_noisy_problem_t *coco_problem_allocate_bbob_wrap_noisy_n_peaks(
        coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t_n_peaks coco_problem_bbob_allocator,
        const size_t function,
        const size_t dimension,
        const size_t instance,
        const long rseed,
        const size_t n_peaks,
        const char *problem_id_template,
        const char *problem_name_template );`
   ```

But this seems to me to be pretty cumbersome, not very elegant nor very efficient way  to do it.

I was wondering whether there is the posssibility, in the C programming language, to create some sort of type union that would allow to write one single wrapper for these two particular cases, instead of one for each. I am new to C so there is a lot of thing that I do not actually know, maybe this is not even possible with this programming language, but I thought I could just ask here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the answer is don't. It sounds like you're going to build some convoluted code that saves a few lines of source and causes many lines on furrowed brows trying to work out what you did. You could create a union containing either a `size_t` or `double` for the varying parameter but at some point the code (presumably) needs to decide which 'version' is being called and so the mangling together of execution paths needs to be eventually un-mangled. The answer is just don't mangle in the first place and you won't be picking hard-to-find data corruptions of your code!